# Yarn Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--check-files")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node-modules, yarnpkg, nvm

When I try to run `yarn install --check-files` on a rails repo that I cloned I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--check-files").

$ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--check-cache] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
```

- I've tried updating yarn and node to the latest stable versions
- I've tried deleting yarn/node modules and yarn.lock in the local folder and running `yarn install` again
- I've tried `yarn upgrade --latest` which also brings up a similar error `Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "upgrade".`
- I'm currently using volta to manage my versions and have not had too much trouble up until now.
  I've previously run --check-files on other repos with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

Ok turns out my system was running yarn 3.* globally which was conflicting with my rails version (6.0.5). I had originally installed yarn using brew so I had to uninstall and start again with npm using the following steps:

1. `brew uninstall yarn` to remove yarn with brew
2. `npm install -g yarn` to install yarn with npm
3. `yarn set version classic` to set yarn version to 1.*
4. `yarn -v` to make sure I was on version 1.*